# Reading data from URL at the time of app running

Tags: flutter, dart

The below flutter code is running fine, this code is simple the autogenerated sample, with the velow statement that reads data from url had been added to the `void _incrementCounter()` function :

```dart
      new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'))
          .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
          .then((HttpClientResponse response) => response.transform(new Utf8Decoder()).listen(print));
```

Full code is:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
//////// Here is the statement /////
      new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'))
          .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
          .then((HttpClientResponse response) => response.transform(new Utf8Decoder()).listen(print));
///////////////////////////////////
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

What I need actually is to execute my function, by reading data from the URL at the time the app is started, I tried putting it under `class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>` but got an error, as below, how can I call it without waiting for action from the user:

[image]

Comment: what you're looking for is initState. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/EditableTextState/initState.html place what you want to execute below super.initState() and remove the rest of the code except for @override found in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create **Function** like this :

```html
getApiParsing()async{
var url = 'https://example.com/whatsit/create';
var response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');

print(await http.read('https://example.com/foobar.txt'));
}
```

And call in **initState** like this:-

```html
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getApiParsing();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { //... // }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = 'https://example.com/whatsit/create';
var response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');

print(await http.read('https://example.com/foobar.txt'));
```

and put your code at your current position will be fine.

Comment: I got this error: The `await` expression can be only used with `async`

Comment: You have to put your code in a function marked async. I suggest you to try to understand asynchronous programming first. https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await